# how to connect cordova project through postgreSql with jdbc

Tags: cordova, jdbc, cordova-plugins

I am trying to connect my cordova app through jdbc from npmjs.
but unable to fetch the data from postgreSql. i tried a lot but not able to do it.
can anyone help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcgjV.png)

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please provide as much information as you can, it's very hard to answer questions with this little knowledge about the actual problem.

Comment: from npmjs site i have install jdbc plugin in my cordova app and i was able to load the jdbc but not able to connect it to the postgreSQL server.